# How to add a list of field names to a class based on NamedTuple?

Tags: python, class, list-comprehension, namedtuple

I have a basic class like this:

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class A(NamedTuple):
    f1: str = ""


aa = A("haha")
print(aa)
```

Now suppose I have a list of more fields that I want to use in `Class A`, essentially:

`more_field_names = ['f2', 'f3', 'f4']`

and I want to make `Class A` look like this, **but without manually typing all the field names**:

```
class A(NamedTuple):
    f1: str = ""
    f2: str = ""
    f3: str = ""
    f4: str = ""
```

Is there a way to use something like list comprehension to add each field names to the `Class A` definition?

Comment: even if you could, would field and type completion work if it were dynamically added?

Comment: " but without manually typing all the field names:" why? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you saying you want `A` to be declared with just `f1`, but then at runtime you want to be able to add a number of fields to the class so that you could do something like `A(f1="a", f2="b", f3="c", f4="d")` without actually changing the source definition?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, it's because in my real codes, there are way more elements in the `more_field_names` list. I want to make my code look more 'pythonic' - otherwise the `Class A` definition will be too long. Does it make sense?

Comment: @user3768495 the *pythonic* way of doing it would be to write it all out. If your class has a lot of attributes, that is fundamentally a design problem, which isnt remedied by simply using some dynamic class creation to cover up that fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not *entirely* sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can dynamically generate the class definition to copy-paste into a python file, based on a list of fields that you want to add (assuming you have a lot of same-type fields to add):

```py
def gen_named_tuple_schema(fields: list[str], class_name='A'):
    fields = '\n'.join(f"    {f}: str = ''" for f in fields)
    return f'class {class_name}(NamedTuple):\n{fields}'
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
print(gen_named_tuple_schema(['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4']))
```

Output:

```py
class A(NamedTuple):
    f1: str = ''
    f2: str = ''
    f3: str = ''
    f4: str = ''
```

---

I would add that, even though it is technically possible to run `exec()` on the generated code, I would honestly not recommend it. The reason is that type checkers won't know the type of `A` by default, so they won't be able to offer field auto-completion and type checking.

For example, in my case PyCharm does not complain at all if I do this:

```py
return_dict = {}
exec(gen_named_tuple_schema(['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4']),
     {'NamedTuple': typing.NamedTuple},
     return_dict)
A = return_dict['A']  # my type checker: what is A?

print(A(1, '2', 3, '4'))   # A(f1=1, f2='2', f3=3, f4='4')
```

Comment: I don't see how that answers op's question; generating the class definition is not generating the class.

Comment: This is a valid solution.  I would add that it is possible to run *exec()* on the generated code to actually create the class.  This is how dataclasses work internally.

Comment: I had the same feeling as @KonstantinosKokos had initially. But after reading Raymond Hettinger's comment, I tested it out and it did create the class as I needed. Thank you both! I didn't know about the exec() before this!

Comment: I updated to mention a possible usage with `exec()`, but note that this approach is definitely not ideal. The reason is that you might lose out benefits of type checkers with a dynamically generated class. However, it is still something that is possible to do.

Comment: Glad it helps OP, but for the sake of anyone else reading this I'll just say meta-programming is the nuclear option and not a good practice for things as trivial as the current question.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from typing import NamedTuple
fields = {f'f{i}': str for i in range(5)}
foo = NamedTuple('foo', **fields)
print(foo.__annotations__)
# {'f0': str, 'f1': str, 'f2': str, 'f3': str, 'f4': str}
```

Comment: thanks! I am glad to know this method works!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [namedtuple()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) factory function from the collections module.  As [shown in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._fields), it is well suited to supplying the field names as data:

```
from collections import namedtuple

A = namedtuple('A', ('f1'))
B = namedtuple('B', A._fields + ('f2', 'f3', 'f4'))
```

Optionally default values can given as well:

```
Person = namedtuple('Person', ('name', 'age', 'points'), defaults=(0, 0))
```

Annotations can be added dynamically using the same technique as in the [code for NamedTuple](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/typing.py#L2814):

```
types = {'name': str, 'age': int, 'points': int}
Person.__annotations__ = Person.__new__.__annotations__ = types
```

Dynamically added types will show-up in tool tips, [help()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help), and calls to [inspect.get_signature()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.get_annotations).  Static type checkers such as [MyPy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) may have trouble with dynamically generated information.

Comment: not what the op asked for; this is untyped

Comment: @KonstantinosKokos That's now how I read the question. It doesn't mention typing at all.  Also, dynamically added annotations are mostly useless because static type checkers can't find them.

Comment: That's not how you read the question, but that's what OP asked, look at their example. Annotations added through the `typing.NamedTuple` are not dynamic, unlike the ad-hoc modification to the class attributes you're proposing.

Comment: Several thoughts:  1) The OP specifically asked to "add a list of field names".  2) Adding fields as described isn't ad-hoc, it is how the *namedtuple()* docs teach how to do this (that was the main motivation for the `_fields` attribute)  3). The implementation of `typing.NamedTuple` does almost exactly what I described in terms of creating the named tuple and adding the annotations:  https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/typing.py#L2814